# Handle unexpected Lauterbach T32-Remote API connection aborts

Tags: remote-access, trace32, lauterbach

Imagine you are using or developing an automated test for the T32-Remote API. In this case the C-API is wrapped into Java.

The connection is initialized with:

```
T32_Config("NODE=", "localhost"));
T32_Config("PACKLEN=", "1024"));
T32_Config("PORT=", "20000"));
T32_Init());
T32_Attach(T32.T32_DEV_ICE);
```

After that, the test starts and is aborted unexpectedly by the user without calling:

```
T32_Exit();
```

If you are restarting the test again now, this results in a connection error at `T32_Attach()` returning -1 (T32_ERR_COM_RECEIVE_FAIL). Restarting a second time does not cause any issues.

Is there any way from within the remote API to reset Trace32? Closing the program and open it again or restarting the test a second time is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really know why this fixed the issue but if an error occurs, simply run the entire initialization routine again.

1st time: T32_Exit() not called

2nd time: simply do this

```
T32_Config("NODE=", "localhost"));
T32_Config("PACKLEN=", "1024"));
T32_Config("PORT=", "20000"));
T32_Init());

if(T32_Attach(T32.T32_DEV_ICE) != 0){
   T32_Config("NODE=", "localhost"));
   T32_Config("PACKLEN=", "1024"));
   T32_Config("PORT=", "20000"));
   T32_Init());
   T32_Attach(T32.T32_DEV_ICE)
}
```